Number Theory: Prove that if a is coprime to 35, $a^{12}$ gives a remainder of 1 when divided by 35.
My Attempt is as follows:
If a is coprime to $35$, a must be coprime to $7$ and coprime to $5$.
Therefore by Fermat's little theorem, ${a}^{6}$gives a remainder of $1$ when divided by $7$, and ${a}^{4}$ gives a remainder of $1$ when divided by $5$.
${a}^{12}$ = ${7}\cdot {k} + {1}$ because of properties of congruent modulo
${a}^{12}$ = ${5}\cdot {m} + {1}$ because of properties of congruent modulo
since $7k=5m\;, 5|7k$ and $7|5m\;, k$ must be divisible by $5$ and $m$ must be divisible by $7$
${a}^{12}$ gives a remainder of $1$ when divisible by $35$.
Is my proof correct?

Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Perhaps you should elaborate what you mean by “properties of congruent modulo”

Do you know chinese remainder theorem? No matter, its essentially what you did.  Your proof is correct but it's HUGE peeve of mine when people say things such as $a^{12} = 7\cdot k + 1$ without introducing $k$.  I want to pin them in a corner and say "why? what is $k$.  What if $k =19$?  Are you really claiming that $a^{12} =134$"  It's not really that hard to type "for same integer $k$", is it?  But your proof is correct (but so would just citing the Chinese Remainder Theorem)

Also here, if you prefer just $35$ :-)

For a solution-verification question to be on topic you must specify precisely which step in the proof you question, and why so. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine.

I like your solution. It's like,  from scratch. That's almost always good.
To use a different approach,  and a couple more advanced theorems,  $\Bbb Z_{35}^×\cong \Bbb Z_7^××\Bbb Z_5^×\cong \Bbb Z_6×\Bbb Z_4\cong \Bbb Z_2×\Bbb Z_{12}.$
From this we easily see that $\Bbb Z_{35}^×$ has exponent $12.$
Succinctly,  if $\lambda$ is Carmichael's function,  then $\lambda (35)=12.$

Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see here.

Your proof is correct.  I'm going to offer an alternative approach.
If $a$ is coprime to $35$, then $a \equiv b \pmod {35}$, where $b \in U(35)$, the multiplicative group of units in $\Bbb Z / 35 \Bbb Z$, and $1 \leq b \leq 34$.  Of course, $a^{12} \equiv b^{12} \pmod {35}$.  Thus, we can work with $b$ without loss of generality.
It's easy to see that there are $24$ numbers less than $35$ that are coprime to $35$; i.e., $U(35)$ has order $24$.  It's also easy to see that $U(35)$ isn't cyclic, because a cyclic group can have at most one element of order $2$, whereas $U(35)$ has at least $3$ such elements -- $34 (\equiv -1 \pmod {35}), 6, 29 (\equiv -6 \pmod {35})$.
By Sylow's Theorem, $U(35)$ must have an element $x$ of order $3$.  It cannot also have an element $y$ of order $8$, because if such an element $y$ did exist, then $xy$ would have order $24$ and $U(35)$ would be cyclic after all.  Thus, the only possible orders of elements of $U(35)$ are $1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12$, so $\forall z \in U(35), z^{12}=1$.

Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see here.
